# Extract properties from JSON Schema inside allOf

Tags: json, typescript, jsonschema

One useful feature of TypeScript is the ability to extract types from a JSON file, with the typeof keyword, like so:

```js
import someSchema from './schema.json'

export type SomeProperties = typeof someSchema.properties
```

However, if the properties are within conditionals like `allOf` this approach doesn't work. Does anybody know how to extract types from JSON Schema in this scenario?